# String.Contains doesn't require parameters in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, contains

I've stumbled upon this code:

```
var knownSeparators = new[] { "\\", "/", "|", "." };
return knownSeparators.FirstOrDefault(path.Contains);
```

where path is a string and the return value should be a string as well.

Allthough path.Contains' intellisense suggests a parameter, it works fine without one.

How does this work exactly?
Is there any way to copy this behavior in vb.net?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` takes a delegate (a `Func<T, bool>`) and this call is creating a delegate from the *method group*. It's equivalent to:

```
Func<string, bool> predicate = path.Contains;
return knownSeparators.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
```

I suspect in VB.NET you could do:

```
Return knownSeparators.FirstOrDefault(AddressOf path.Contains)
```

... but I couldn't tell for sure without trying it.

Comment: Sadly, it still gives the same error saying it requires a parameter (after adding the addressOf)

Comment: @djerry: I've edited to remove the brackets - see if that helps.